# duplicate class android.support.v4.accessibilityservice

Tags: java, android

duplicate class android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat found in modules support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and support-v4-22.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0)

please what should I do, I have no idea and Im new to android studio

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
//implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}